# ¿como traer un registro de una tabla si y solo si se cumple un estado en registros de otra tabla referanciada al id de la primera?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Lo que busco obtener es que si la asignatura tiene correlativas, que todas esten en estado 1, aprobadas, y si tiene alguna no aprobada o no está en el historial que no traiga la asignatura. Tengo tres tablas:

> asignatura(id, descripcion)
>   correlativas(id, idAsignatura, idCorrelativas)
>   historial(id, idAsignatura, estado)

Aclaro que la correlativa, significa que el derecho de rendir la actual depende de la aprobación de sus correlativas. Cada asignatura puede tener una, varias, o ninguna correlativa.

Actualmente hago la consulta buscando el id de la asignatura, con esta busco sus correspondientes correlativas y con ellas busco en el historial del alumno si las tiene aprobada.

Mi problema aparece cuando trato de traer la materia sólo si tiene todas las correlativas en estado 1, que seria aprobado. Pero al hacer la consulta me trae la asignatura si esta tiene una sola de las correlativas aprobadas aunque, por ejemplo, tenga dos o mas.  Mi consulta es:

```
SELECT as.*  
FROM asignatura as, correlativas co, historial hi  
WHERE as.id = co.idAsignatura   
AND co.idCorrelativa = hi.idAsignatura  
AND hi.estado = 1
```

> asignatura
>   id    descripcion
>   1    Matematica
>   2    Matematica II
>   3    Contabilidad
>   4    Economia
>
> correlativas
>   id    idAs    idCo
>   1__3__1
>   2__3__2
>   3__4__2
>   4__4__3
>
> historial
>   id    idAs    estado
>   1__1__1
>   2__2__1
>   3__3__0

El resultado esperado es obtener sólo Contabilidad.
Se obtiene contabilidad y Economía, ya que esta última tiene una correlativa aprobada de las 2 que le están asignada.

Saludos y gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Podrias agregar unos datos de ejemplo, y la salida esperada con esos datos? es para facilitar a quien te quiera ayudar a probar su solucion

Comment: ¿porque el resultado esperado es Contabilidad, si Contabilidad aparece como reprobada en el historial?

Comment: Hola Alberto, la idea es que la materia que me devuelve se puede inscribir a cursar, con lo cual si puede contabilidad, ya que aprobó sus correlativas,  pero no puede hacer con economía xq todavía no aprobó una de sus correlativas, que es contabilidad